# Python for loop problem about list and list[:]

Tags: python, list, for-loop, web-scraping, scrape

I wrote a program to scrape links from google search. I created a list for links and after that I created a tuple about google domains. No problem so far. When I created a for loop to remove links that starts with google domains from the link list, I noticed something. If I use "for link in links:" the links that starts with google domains are not removing, If I use "for link in links[:]:" the links that starts with google domains are removing.

```
from sys import argv, exit
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pprint

if len(argv) < 2:
    exit()
else:
    searchingText = '+'.join(argv[1:])

response = HTMLSession().get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={searchingText}')
sleep(2)
print(response.raise_for_status())

soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
aObject = soup.select('.yuRUbf a')
print(len(aObject))

links = list(response.html.absolute_links)
googleDomains = ('https://www.google.', 
                      'https://google.')

for link in links[:]:
    if link.startswith(googleDomains):
        links.remove(link)

pprint.pprint(links)
```

What is difference between links and links[:] in for loop? I would also be grateful If you have any advice about my syntax or codes.

Comment: `links[:]` creates s shallow copy of the list because you should not modify a list (as `links.remove(link)` does) while iterating over it.

Comment: `links = [link for link in links if not link.startswith(googleDomains)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Comment: The link you sent is similar but it does not explain exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you.